# How to add WPF datagrid Programatically and setting other properties

Tags: wpf, binding

My Quetion is,
How to add WPF datagrid Programatically and set ItemsSource Propery in c# code as XAML equivalant {Binding}.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the parent container, you can operate in different way. Just imagine to do it in XAML and then write the equivalent code in C#. XAML is always transable in C#. Setting ItemSource is just assign the property ItemSource , and {Binding} means passing DataContext.